# Efficient way ResultSet GetString with isEmpty check Java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

In **Approach-1** execute *rs.getString("COL_NAME")* twice (process redundancy).

```
//Approach 1
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(rs.getString("COL_NAME"))) {
 testData.setTestNumber(rs.getString("COL_NAME").trim());
}
```

In **Approach-2** we initialize a string (mmy initialization).

```
//Approach 2
String value = rs.getString("COL_NAME");
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
 testData.setTestNumber(value.trim());
}
```

Which one of the method will be most efficient ?
Is there any other better way to do the null check and get perform operation efficiently.

Comment: It is of course more efficient to not call the method twice.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously more efficient to avoid calling on the `ResultSet` repeatedly.

In your example code, efficiency is not likely to be at issue there. And there is no shortcut to any dramatic efficiency breakthrough there. So, better to make your code is easier to read and maintain by separating your database retrieval code from your other business logic.

So get the values from your database.

```
String customerName = myResultSet.getString( "cust_name_" ) ;
```

Do a basic null check there if appropriate.

```
String customerName = Objects.requireNonNull( myResultSet.getString( "cust_name_" ) ) ;
```

Then do your business logic. No need for *StringUtils* library. Modern versions of `String` class offers the `isBlank` and `isEmpty` methods.

```
if ( customerName.isEmpty() || customerName.isBlank() ) {…}
```